# Transfer block in table-cell on a new line

Tags: css, flexbox

I’m writing a template for marking on flex/box. And faced with the problem of emulation of some properties. At the moment, I decide them on JS. What complicates code.

So I decided to try to use the property of `table-cell` for child elements whose parent has the property `display: block`. Yes, it’s not right, but it works!

When I’m trying to break the table-cell elements to strings, I ran into a problem. And that’s how I tried to solve them:

- If the child blocks `table-cell` overflow the parent horizontally, then
  the following blocks are not transferred to the new line. And it is
  logical. Example: **Nowrap** in link.
- If I use the cancel flow, I lose equal to the width of columns for the element to be wrapped to the next line. So, this method only works for IE9+. I’m willing to drop IE7, but not ready to abandon IE8. Example: **Wrap nth-of-type** in link.
- If I use the blocks which separate the `table-cell` on the line, everything becomes fine! But this complicates the CSS and JS code. Example: **Wrap with break elements** in link.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmgXmO

---

What ways to break `table-cell` can be applied, besides the above described options?

An example of a 12 column layout, fix the problem of calculation of the width percentage: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmwRvK
In order to make it clear why I do this.

I will be glad to hear your answers! And excuse me for my bad English.

**P.S.:** Ignore the strange size of the width in percent. It is calculated
 according to the formula:

`(100 * element.clientWidth / element.offsetWidth)`.

The smaller size, so it is more. Funny.  This rule is applicable only to
 the parent `display: block` containing the child elements `display: table-cell`

Comment: I have difficulties understanding what you want. Could you post 2(or 3) images, for the 2(or 3) layouts you want to achieve

Comment: @LGSon
How to break a string with the elements `display: table-cell` and the parent element `display: block`? **With conditions**: **1.** You cannot use the block wrappers for a group of child elements `display: table-cell`. **2.** Keep the same height for all line items. As in the example "Wrap with break elements" http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmgXmO **3.** Width of the child elements may be different. They should not behave like a table with columns and rows. _At the moment I insert a block which moves items to a new row using JS. I need an idea =)_